# canvas controlling by ontouchlistener

Tags: android, android-canvas, draw

I made a two small rectangle by using canvas but i faced a small problem . I don't know how to control the two rectangles by onTouchlistener and move it vertically and horizontally .

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
  if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
    view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
    view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
 }
}
```

Check for more details on this [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html).

Comment: that helped me very well , any advice of a good websites or videos that teach android from the begging ?

Comment: are looking for Android SDK or Android NDK?

Comment: is there a different between them :) ?

Comment: SDK is when you plan to program mostly only using java. NDK is for when you are going to make development on Android using C++. Then, of course the approach is different, and reference material too.

Comment: ok if I would like to make a program for that works like instagram or twitter which one should I use it ? SDK or NDK ?